# Html video to vlc deep link

Tags: html, lua, registry, vlc

i need help about opening vlc with html deeplink

I have already a ps1 script for add registry key, a URL Protocol on "vlcurl", so on my html :
`<a href="vlcurl:http://127.0.0.1:5500/ship.mp4">Video</a>`

The big issue with this is the redirection, vlc try to open the link with the "vlcurl" at the start causing issue :

> Your input can't be opened:
> VLC is unable to open the MRL 'vlcurl:[http://127.0.0.1:5500/ship.mp4'](http://127.0.0.1:5500/ship.mp4%27). Check the log for details.

The goal is to remove the "vlcurl" when we send this to vlc

I have try to create a lua script for a plugin to vlc, but it dosen't work (i'm no't really good in lua) and try to find if we can add logic in a registry key (like if there is "vlcurl" in the "%1" remove it) but apparently we can't

I would avoid to make many step to do on the computer for making this work, the project is to share it with ma family, so have to setup the ps1 is already a lot

Comment: Could it be http vs https?

Comment: @mplungjan no, if i start a network stream on vlc, with http or https with the same adress is okay, is only the "vlcurl:" causing issue